# Targeting a specific charged (macroscopic) particle in a particle trap

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

I, for a project, want to build a Paul trap ([quadrupole trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_ion_trap)), and in there store a bunch of particles, in my specific case grains of flour, and I want to put an electrode, that basically extracts individual grains, while leaving the others in the trap, and I'm not sure how.

Is it even possible? If so, which variable should be used to "identify a particle"? I don't think I can give them differing charges, but perhaps I could extract them based on mass, or their frequency, but I assume that this would change in the RF-field. If someone has ideas, please help!